# how user to stop selecting the select option without disabling it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select option in my form. It will be selected by the user once and make a ajax request to the server on change and render a form. That rendered form also contains the same field with the option he/she selected. So i dont want them to select the option again. By disabling it the form will not submit its value. So what will be an option for that.

Comment: You could remove it?

Comment: at the end of your ajax request set each <option> tag to be disabled. For example it should result in <select><option disabled=disabled value="whatever"></option></select>

Comment: no, it has to be submitted

Comment: you could set the attribute of the selected option to selected i.e. <option value="whatever" selected>whatever</option>

Comment: may be make it read only.

Comment: you can use the hidden field instead of select in the rendering form, so that when you submit the form you can get the value

Comment: Other thing you can do is that you should keep the select element disabled but also add another hidden input with the same name and value.

Comment: Why don't you remove all other options of your type on the ajax call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**  You can track the user selected options so far by storing indexes in an array. Thus before making ajax call you can check if there is already succesful call made or not. On each successful call you would push it in the array.

```
var queriedItems = [];
function onItemChange(this) {
    var index = this.selectedIndex; //value can also be used
    if (queriedItems.indexOf(index) === -1) { //not queried so far
        /*perform ajax call
          onscussess/readystatechanged
            queriedItems.push(index)       
       */
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** Construct custom drop down using css and divs instead of html select. It will allow you the flexibility to add appropriate css classes to mimic that a particular option already selected by user. You can easily find how to implement custom drop down by little googling.
You can have hidden fields to store the selected value so that it would be submitted by default to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use double event on that `select` created by ajax like this

```
var val ="";
$('#check').on('click',function(){
    val=$(this).val();
});

$('#check').change(function(){
$(this).val(val);
})
```

***[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ztLwzc8e/)***